# data structure for ResultSet

Tags: java, database

Working with database in java requires a set of lines of code to be written. If the database connection is established again-n-again the same set of lines need to be repeated again-n-again which creates an overhead to programmer.

Hence, I am making a utility class which works as a database agent. The method of this class will be responsible for all the database related stuff from establishing a connection to executing a query and returning the result.

My class goes like this -

```
package connect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Connector
{
private ResultSet rs;
public String password;

public void connect(String dbUrl, String dbClass, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String query)
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName(this.dbClass).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, dbUserName, dbPassword);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            this.password = (String) rs.getObject(1);
        }

        conn.close();
    } //end try
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

When a programmer needs a query to be executed, below lines can be written for that purpose -

```
Connector con = new Connector();
con.connect("your database URL",
            "your database driver",
            "your database username",
            "your database password",
            "your query");
```

My question here is that right now I am retreiving the data from ResultSet in the connect method itself. The retreived data can vary from query-to-query hence I want a data structure in which I can store the data from rs in connect() method and return it.

It will look like -

```
<data structure> result = con.connect("your database URL",
                                      "your database driver",
                                      "your database username",
                                      "your database password",
                                      "your query");
```

Can someone please suggest me a data structure for this purpose?

Comment: You should read about the "standards": Hibernate, [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), etc

Comment: @PeterMmm Well, Hibernate and Spring does that but my project requirement does not allow me to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're re-inventing this particular wheel, and it seems like if you're repeatedly connecting for every query you're basically writing yourself out of any performance, but why not just use [RowSetDynaClass](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/index.html) if you're not going to map to objects?

Just be aware that there are a ton of pre-existing solutions that have been tested and proven. And use connection pools; creating connections is expensive.

Comment: connection pool seems to be an interesting one. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of Open Source, implementation like the one you want to do above.

[Spring JDBCTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use any libraries already available to solve your problem, you could use

```
 Vector<Map<String, Object>>
```

Where String contains column name and Object is the value of the column. Each element in the Vector corresponds to a row of the ResultSet. This may not be the most efficient data structure but should get the job done.